# How do I get MinTTY working with UTF8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, mintty

I am using msys mintty on vista.

My font is Deja Vu Sans Mono, which has excellent unicode coverage.

The simplest test is to just cat this file: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt  all non-ascii characters show up as boxed questionmarks.

I have explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8 in mintty's settings.

Similarly pasting non-ascii text into mintty gives me garbage.  What's going on?  Everything I can find tells me that mintty should support unicode just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinTTY supports UTF-8 but MSys does not.  The Cygwin build of MinTTY solved my problem.

Comment: In 2018, the mintty that comes with git for 64-bit windows `mintty 2.9.1 (x86_64-pc-msys)` DOES support the unicode character I wanted to display: ⬢.  The version I installed in 2017 `mintty 2.7.3 (x86_64-pc-msys)` did NOT.